# Microsoft Bot Framework API Add Button with Custom Form in Teams

Tags: node.js, rest, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to send proactive messages to Teams where the User can open a Form. The message should be sent to a Teams Channel with multiple members.

The Form should consist of multiple Text Fields. After the user filled all Text Fields, he should be able to submit the Form. The data should be transmitted to the Bot for further processing.

Is there a Technology in Teams which can accomplish this? In Slack, we have Modals for this use case.

My current idea is to use deep links to forward the User onto a custom Tab in which the Form is. But I'm not sure how I can Tab, which contains a Form where the User is identified.

I have checked the examples on https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this with Teams bots:

1. Task Modules - these are forms that load in their own window and can be either web forms that you self-host, or "Adaptive Cards" forms.
2. Adaptive Cards message right into the chat - probably your simplest option.

See more on both of these at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards-and-task-modules

Note that the link above talks about "Cards" in general, as there are several possible types in Teams, but Adaptive Cards specifically would be best for this. More info also at https://adaptivecards.io/